# Getting duplicate session_id with PHP

Tags: php, magento, session, azure

I'm using PHP 5.4.9 on two Ubuntu Server VM "hosted" in the cloud with Windows Azure and Magento Enterprise under a lot of different domain/subdomain, which means lots of pages which mean lots of crawling from lots of bots. 70% of the traffic must be bots crawling.

Couple weeks ago we started to have a weird issue, where users started seeing account of other user. We activated session verification (which check IP/user agent). If the session doesn't match you get redirected to the home page with a new session_id.

At any moment we have 50k session being stored (bots session only for 2 minutes), 96% are bots session.

For some unknown reason, we're getting session that was already given to other user or to a bot, we haven't change the code of Magento related to session, PHP is the one generating the session_id. Session are stored in Redis, but we've try storing them in MySQL and files with the same problem.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: When you check IP/user agent you're checking against a db rather than PHP session object?

Comment: The IP/User Agent would be stored in each session and compared with each request

Comment: @zzarbi Could you find out the root cause of this? I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Redis with Magento then you'll need to enable the Cm_Redis module.  It's included in CE1.8 and EE1.13 but you'll need to download it for earlier versions.

If you're using EE below 1.13 then try this module from Collin Mollenhour (the CM in Cm_RedisSession).

https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession

I realize that you seem to have the problem with or without Redis but if the only place you're having session issues is Magento then it seems like you have a configuration issue there.  Enabling Redis with this module may help.

Comment: I am using this module, also installed the php redis extension. Which did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not redis in the end. Basically try to check all the php request (including ajax ones) headers and try to find out the faulty one where the session cookie request header value is different than the response header cookie value.

Note: This behavior is fine in case of signin/signup requests. Other than that, it should not happen (in my case a captha request was at fault).